# Angular - Using $http Service in Controller Function

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-service

folks-- so in my continuing Angular adventures, I've run into an issue where $http.get is working for me, but $http.post is not.  It's obvivously an issue of scope (i.e., my controller function sees '$http', but one of its functions cannot.  Here's my code so far:

```
var app = angular.module('docManager', []);
app.controller('DocManCtrl', ['$http', DocManCtrl]);

function DocManCtrl($http){
  var self = this;
  $http.get('http://localhost:3000/documents').success(function(data){
    self.documents = data;
    }).error(function(){
    console.log('Error: could not GET documents');
  });
}

DocManCtrl.prototype.addDoc = function(){
  var self = this;
  self.documents.push({filename: this.filename, category: this.category});
  $http.post('http://localhost:3000/documents', self.documents).success(function(data){
  console.log('document posted.');
  }).error(function(){
  console.log('document not posted');
  });
};
```

My HTML page displays all the records via the $http.get method, but the controller's 'addDoc' method (triggered by a form submit) is causing a '$http not defined' error when I try to post data to my backend. So-- how can I get $http injected into my addDoc method?

Thanks!
Bryan

Comment: A cleaner workaround instead of messing with scoping issues and that might be more similar to other Angular code you see on the web would be to not use the prototype on the controller and move that logic in addDoc to a service that has $http injected into it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really want to use controllers with instance methods, you have to create a reference to the injected services on self:

```js
var app = angular.module('docManager', []);
app.controller('DocManCtrl', ['$http', DocManCtrl]);

function DocManCtrl($http) {
  var self = this;
  self._http = $http; // <== For use in instance methods.

  self.documents = [];
  $http.get('http://localhost:3000/documents').success(function(data) {
    self.documents = data;
  }).error(function() {
    console.log('Error: could not GET documents');
  });
}

DocManCtrl.prototype.addDoc = function() {
  var self = this;
  self.documents.push({
    filename: this.filename,
    category: this.category
  });
  self._http.post('http://localhost:3000/documents', self.documents).success(function(data) {
    console.log('document posted.');
  }).error(function() {
    console.log('document not posted');
  });
};
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app='docManager' ng-controller='DocManCtrl as vm'>
  <button ng-click="vm.addDoc()">Add Doc</button>
</div>
```

Here are some references:

- http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2421-creating-angularjs-controllers-with-instance-methods.htm
- https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/68479/monkey-patching-angularjs-controllers-to-have-instance-functions-with-injectable